# Hashtable with separate chaining and dynamic resizing

Tags: c, hash-map

An attempt at a clean implementation of this important data structure in C.

It's hard to make such structures generic in C without losing performance, so this specialises on `char*` keys and `int` values, but uses some type aliases, such that only a few places need changing to change the key or value types.

The hash table dynamically grows by 2x when 80% of the slots are used to keep efficiency high.

As a demo, we parse the [complete works of Shakespeare](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/6/6.006/s08/lecturenotes/files/t8.shakespeare.txt), call `ht_inc()` for each word. Then build a flat "view" of the hashtable, sort and report the 10 most common words. On my machine the entire task takes just 50ms.

Feedback on quality of coding style please.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char* ht_key_t;
typedef int   ht_value_t;

// key => value plus pointer to next item for hash collisions
typedef struct HashTableItem HashTableItem;
struct HashTableItem {
  ht_key_t       key;
  ht_value_t     value;
  HashTableItem* next;
};

// Array of pointers to HashTableItems, plus counters
typedef struct HashTable {
  HashTableItem** slots;
  size_t          size;      // how many slots are there
  size_t          scount;    // how many slots are used
  size_t          itemcount; // how many items are there
} HashTable;

// Creates a new HashTableItem 
HashTableItem* ht_create_item(ht_key_t key, ht_value_t value) {
  HashTableItem* item = malloc(sizeof *item);
  if (!item) {
    perror("malloc item");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  item->key   = strdup(key); // take a copy
  item->value = value;
  item->next  = NULL;
  return item;
}

// Creates a new HashTable
HashTable* ht_create(size_t size) {
  HashTable* table = malloc(sizeof *table);
  if (!table) {
    perror("malloc table");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  table->size      = size;
  table->scount    = 0;
  table->itemcount = 0;
  table->slots     = calloc(table->size, sizeof *table->slots); // NOLINT
  if (!table->slots) {
    perror("calloc items");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return table;
}

// Frees an item depending on their types, if the key or value members
// need freeing that needs to happen here too
void ht_free_item(HashTableItem* item) {
  free(item->key);
  free(item);
}

// Frees the whole hashtable
void ht_free(HashTable* table) {
  // free the HashTableItems in the linked lists
  for (size_t i = 0; i < table->size; i++) {
    HashTableItem* item = table->slots[i];
    while (item) {
      HashTableItem* next = item->next;
      ht_free_item(item);
      item = next;
    }
  }
  // free the array of pointers to HashTableItems
  free(table->slots);
  free(table);
}

// hash function. crucial to efficient operation
// returns value in range [0, size)
// an appropriate hash function for short strings is FNV-1a
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function#FNV-1a_hash
size_t ht_hash(size_t size, const char* str) {
  uint64_t hash = 0xcbf29ce484222325; // FNV_offset_basis
  while (*str) hash = (hash ^ (uint8_t)*str++) * 0x100000001b3; // FNV_prime
  return hash % size;                                           // fit to table
}

void ht_grow(HashTable* table) {
  table->scount++;
  if (table->scount * 100 / table->size >= 80) {
    size_t          nsize  = table->size * 2;
    HashTableItem** nslots = calloc(nsize, sizeof *table->slots); // NOLINT
    if (!nslots) {
      perror("calloc nitems");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size_t ncount = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < table->size; i++) {
      HashTableItem* item = table->slots[i];
      while (item) {
        HashTableItem*  next  = item->next; // save next
        HashTableItem** nslot = &nslots[ht_hash(nsize, item->key)];
        if (!*nslot) ++ncount;
        item->next = *nslot; // push into new list
        *nslot     = item;
        item       = next;
      }
    }
    free(table->slots);
    table->scount = ncount;
    table->size   = nsize;
    table->slots  = nslots;
  }
}

// Inserts an item (or updates if exists)
void ht_insert(HashTable* table, ht_key_t key, ht_value_t value) {
  HashTableItem** slot           = &table->slots[ht_hash(table->size, key)];
  HashTableItem*  item           = *slot;
  bool            direct_slot     = true;
  while (item) {
    if (strcmp(item->key, key) == 0) {
      // exists, update value, free old value if needed
      item->value = value;
      return;
    }
    slot           = &item->next;
    item           = *slot;
    direct_slot     = false;
  }
  *slot = ht_create_item(key, value); // new entry
  ++table->itemcount;
  if (direct_slot) ht_grow(table); // HashTable accounting
}

// increments the value for a key or inserts with value = 1
// specialised for ht_value_t=int and faster than search then update.
void ht_inc(HashTable* table, ht_key_t key) {
  HashTableItem** slot           = &table->slots[ht_hash(table->size, key)];
  HashTableItem*  item           = *slot;
  bool            direct_slot     = true;
  while (item) {
    if (strcmp(item->key, key) == 0) {
      ++item->value;
      return;
    }
    slot           = &item->next;
    item           = *slot;
    direct_slot     = false;
  }
  *slot = ht_create_item(key, 1); // not found, init with one
  ++table->itemcount;
  if (direct_slot) ht_grow(table); // HashTable accounting
}

// Deletes an item from the table
void ht_delete(HashTable* table, ht_key_t key) {
  HashTableItem** slot           = &table->slots[ht_hash(table->size, key)];
  HashTableItem*  item           = *slot;
  bool            direct_slot     = true;
  while (item) {
    if (strcmp(item->key, key) == 0) {
      *slot = item->next; // remove item from linked list
      ht_free_item(item);
      --table->itemcount;
      if (direct_slot) --table->scount; // HashTable accounting
      return;
    }
    slot           = &item->next;
    item           = *slot;
    direct_slot     = false;
  }
}

// Searches the key in the hashtable
// and returns NULL ptr if it doesn't exist
HashTableItem* ht_search(HashTable* table, ht_key_t key) {
  HashTableItem* item = table->slots[ht_hash(table->size, key)];
  while (item) {
    if (strcmp(item->key, key) == 0) return item;
    item = item->next;
  }
  return NULL;
}

// debug printing. customise printf format strings by key & value types
void ht_print(HashTable* table) {
  printf("\n---- Hash Table ---\n");
  for (size_t i = 0; i < table->size; i++) {
    printf("@%zu: ", i);
    HashTableItem* item = table->slots[i];
    while (item) {
      printf("%s => %d | ", item->key, item->value);
      item = item->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("-------------------\n");
}

// debug printing. customise printf format strings by key & value types
void ht_print_search(HashTable* table, ht_key_t key) {
  HashTableItem* val;
  if ((val = ht_search(table, key)) == NULL) {
    printf("Key:%s does not exist\n", key);
    return;
  }
  printf("Key:%s => %d\n", key, val->value);
}

static inline bool ht_is_alpha(char c) {
  return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}
static inline char ht_tolower(char c) { return (c < 'a') ? c + 'a' - 'A' : c; }

int cmp_ht_items(const void* a, const void* b) {
  int a_val = (*(HashTableItem**)a)->value;
  int b_val = (*(HashTableItem**)b)->value;
  if (a_val == b_val) return 0;
  return a_val < b_val ? 1 : -1;
}

int main() {
  // some tests
  HashTable* ht = ht_create(4);
  ht_insert(ht, "1", 10);
  ht_insert(ht, "2", 20);
  ht_insert(ht, "Hel3", 30);
  ht_insert(ht, "Cau4", 40);
  ht_print(ht);
  ht_insert(ht, "Cau6", 60); // grow!
  ht_print(ht);
  ht_inc(ht, "11"); // increment
  ht_inc(ht, "21"); // increment
  ht_inc(ht, "31"); // increment
  ht_inc(ht, "41"); // increment
  ht_inc(ht, "51"); // increment
  ht_inc(ht, "61"); // increment
  ht_inc(ht, "71"); // increment
  ht_inc(ht, "81"); // increment and grow again
  ht_print(ht);

  ht_print_search(ht, "1");
  ht_print_search(ht, "2");
  ht_print_search(ht, "3");
  ht_print_search(ht, "Hel3");
  ht_print_search(ht, "Cau4");

  ht_insert(ht, "Cau6", 61); // update
  ht_inc(ht, "1");           // increment
  ht_inc(ht, "Hel3");        // increment
  ht_inc(ht, "new");         // increment
  ht_print(ht);

  ht_delete(ht, "Hel3");
  ht_delete(ht, "Cau6");
  ht_delete(ht, "1");
  ht_print(ht);

  ht_free(ht);
  // end of tests

  // shakespeare demo
  FILE* fp = fopen("shakespeare.txt", "re");
  if (!fp) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  ht = ht_create(32 * 1024);

#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define WORDSIZE 50
  char  buf[BUFSIZE];
  char  word[WORDSIZE];
  char* word_ptr = word;
  while (!ferror(fp) && !feof(fp)) {
    size_t bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, fp);
    char*  buf_ptr    = buf;
    while ((buf_ptr < buf + bytes_read)) {
      char c = *buf_ptr;
      if (ht_is_alpha(c)) {
        *(word_ptr++) = ht_tolower(c);
        if (word_ptr - word == WORDSIZE - 1) { // -1 for NULL terminator
          fputs("word too long. terminating\n", stderr);
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
      } else if (word_ptr == word) {
        // ignore repeated terminators
      } else {
        *(word_ptr++) = '\0';
        ht_inc(ht, word); // record
        word_ptr = word;  // restart new word
      }
      ++buf_ptr; // next char from buf
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);

  // build a flat view of the hashtable items
  HashTableItem** itemview = malloc(ht->itemcount * sizeof *itemview); // NOLINT
  if (!itemview) {
    perror("malloc itemview");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  HashTableItem** curritem = itemview;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < ht->size; i++) {
    HashTableItem* item = ht->slots[i];
    while (item) {
      *curritem++ = item;
      item        = item->next;
    }
  }
  // now sort that view and print the top 10
  qsort(itemview, ht->itemcount, sizeof *itemview, cmp_ht_items); // NOLINT
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%s => %d\n", itemview[i]->key, itemview[i]->value);

  free(itemview);

  // ht_print(ht);
  ht_free(ht);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Make more use of `calloc()`

I would use `calloc()` almost everywhere. It guarantees the memory is zeroed, so you won't have surprises if you forgot to initialize a member variable. I wouldn't worry about performance much; the compiler should be able to optimize the zeroing away if it sees you are setting a member variable to something else. So, use it in `ht_create_item()` and `ht_create()` where you currently use `malloc()`.

## Consider avoiding a layer of indirection

Your hash table has an array `slots` that contains pointers to items, however items themselves are quite small, they are just two pointers and an `int`. Since you aim at a load factor of 0.4 to 0.8, it will use less memory to remove the indirection:

```
typedef struct HashTable {
  HashTableItem* slots;
  ...
} HashTable;
```

This should also give a small performance gain.

## Avoid code duplication

`ht_inc()` and `ht_delete()` look very similar. It might be possible to put the common parts into a separate function. I think you can do this by creating a function that finds the pointer to where the item should be/go, and return a pointer to that pointer. Basically, a `ht_search()` that returns the slot instead of the item itself.

```
static HashTableItem** ht_search_slot(HashTable* table, ht_key_t key, bool *direct) {
  HashTableItem** slot = &table->slots[ht_hash(table->size, key)];
  *direct = true;
  while (*slot) {
    if (strcmp((*slot)->key, key) == 0) break;
    *direct = false;
    slot = &(*slot)->next;
  }
  return slot;
}

void ht_inc(HashTable* table, ht_key_t key) {
  bool direct_slot;
  HashTableItem** slot = ht_search_slot(table, key, &direct_slot);
  HashTableItem*  item = *slot;
  if (item) {
    ++item->value;
    return;
  }
  *slot = ht_create_item(key, 1); // not found, init with one
  ++table->itemcount;
  if (direct_slot) ht_grow(table); // HashTable accounting
}

void ht_delete(HashTable* table, ht_key_t key) {
  bool direct_slot;
  HashTableItem** slot = ht_search_slot(table, key, &direct_slot);
  HashTableItem*  item = *slot;
  if (item) {
    *slot = item->next; // remove item from linked list
    ht_free_item(item);
    --table->itemcount;
    if (direct_slot) --table->scount; // HashTable accounting
  }
}

HashTableItem* ht_search(HashTable* table, ht_key_t key) {
  bool direct_slot;
  return *ht_search_slot(table, key, &direct_slot);
}
```

Of course, this approach will conflict with the above advice of avoiding indirection, although perhaps something similar is still possible.

## Always call `ht_grow()` when inserting elements

You are only calling `ht_grow()` when an empty direct slot is used. However, if an item is inserted in an already used slot, you don't call it. That means that if you are unlucky, everything hashes to the same slot, and you will never grow and rebalance. I would play it safe and just unconditionally call `ht_grow()` when inserting an element. Of course, `ht_grow()` should use `itemcount` instead of `scount` to check whether it needs to grow the hash table.

## Avoid division and modulo operations

Divisions (and thus also modulo operations) are quite expensive. I would avoid them by ensuring the hash table size is always a power of two. And if you ensure that the size is at least 16 elements, then you can replace the check in `ht_grow()` by:

```
if (table->itemcount >= 13 * (table->size >> 4)) {
  ...
}
```

This will trigger a resize when the hash table is 81.25% full. You can even get rid of the multiplication by storing the binary logarithm of the size, but unless you plan to run this code on microcontrollers I would not bother with that. And in the hash function you can replace the modulo this way:

```
return hash & (size - 1);
```

Comment: Good stuff, thanks. I considered most of these. I kept the indirection to not tie myself to this key=>value structure, but it's certainly debatable. I considered calloc, meh.. The code duplication is very interesting and I was still wrestling with this. Each function is only 10 lines, but they are "somewhat complex" pointer juggling. So not not just duplication but also clarity might improve if I factor out "finding the slot incl linked list part". I thought about load factor by itemcount vs slotcount, more common? And I really like the power of 2 idea and remove modulo/divide.   Thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure this is right? `table->itemcount >= 13 * (table->size >> 2)` I can't seem to make that work in my head. For me that would only trigger at >300% load factor? Or am I missing something?

shouldn't it be `table->itemcount * 10 >= (table->size << 3)` for an 80% cutoff? And no restriction for size >=16 (which breaks my tests). In fact if I do the swap to itemcount, then the threshhold should be more lke 160% but that's easy to adjust.

Comment: Interestingly, removing the `%` modulo in `ht_hash` gave a 20% gain immediately, whereas changing that `if` in `ht_grow` did nothing at all (similar number of calls). I guess on a big Intel CPU division is fast (but modulo is not), so unless I am going for an 8-bit pic18 the division is probably more readable?  (the 8-bit pic can't handle uint64 anyway, nor malloc etc etc...)

Comment: It should've been `>> 4`, which is equal to `/ 16`. In fact you can just write the latter, the compiler is able to optimize that because it can see it's a constant. Your option to do `... * 10 >= ... << 3` should also work, but it might have issues with very large values of `table->size`.

Comment: I tried the `ht_search_slot` refactor for all of `ht_insert` `ht_delete` `ht_inc` and `ht_search`. I took it out again, because: I had already changed to grow by `itemcount` so `is_direct_slot` got removed, so 3 of those methods were even shorter. Of course `item` is redundant in those 4 methods, you can just substitute `*slot` everywhere. BUT that makes it VERY hard to read, at least for my head, which is the reason I had `item` in the first place. And if you have `item` then the refactor makes it "no shorter", and a lot less clear IMO. Perhaps once case were small repetition is clearer?

Comment: Even though it might not make sense anymore from a line count perspective, it might still make the code more self-documenting if you have a function `ht_search_slot()` and have other functions calling that. Maybe you can post your updated version as a new review question?

Comment: The current version is here: https://github.com/oschonrock/cproj/blob/main/src/hashtable.c

I think I have found a way of making it generic which I actually like. I had not seen this before. The idea is from here:  

https://gitlab.com/martinkunev/conquest_of_levidon/-/tree/2019/src/generic

I think of it as "C++ templates for C".... ie you "stamp out" as many version of the "generic code" as you need at top of your file, then use them like they were concrete. ie, no macros in the actual main code. 

I am trying to copy that idea right now, might repost if it works out.

Comment: Personally I think that if you need templates in C, you should just use C++ instead of doing these kinds of contortions. That said, the method you linked to is one of the cleaner ones I've seen :)

Comment: I sort of agree, but, eg the Linux Kernel is written in C, because overall they decided C was the better tool. They needed hashmaps and other data structures too. It's a normal thing to need in a bigger project. Implementing such structures is actually quite slow and fiddly, if you want to do a good job. So because they needed them more than once, they wrote some macros ..those are part of the kernel. They were not about to "switch to C++". Exactly the same story for the BSD Kernel. They wrote this: https://linux.die.net/man/3/queue  It's awful to use in IMO.

Comment: Thought you might like this commit: https://github.com/oschonrock/cproj/commit/536c6cf276e407e488d9f3051232ddeb1d6ecb6b